# where are the teams app binaries hosted, in particular "msteams-samples-hello-world-csharp"

Tags: microsoft-teams

MSFT gives a sample hello world c# app, in github:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-csharp/tree/master/Microsoft.Teams.Samples.HelloWorld.Web

I was able to download/build/generate the helloworld.zip and its manifest file.  I was able to 'upload' the app into a Teams (both web based and desktop).  I did see the tabs, as outlined in manifest.json file.
In the project, there are c# files and the build (Debug or Release) generates the binaries.  Where do these go, are they to be 'deployed' to Teams?  Doesn't 'hello world' need to interact with these methods?

thanks
Art

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: You need to host your sample application in cloud(Azure/AWS).Provide the published URL in your manifest file. MS Teams Does not host any application.You can host it locally also. Could you please Check these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#host-the-sample-app)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to host your sample application in cloud(Azure/AWS).Provide the published URL in your manifest file. MS Teams Does not host any application.You can host it locally also. Could you please Check these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#host-the-sample-app)?